# Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /... on line 21

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I've spent the past 2 hours trying to solve this one error. I am a complete rookie so I dont know what's going on. Here's the code, please help:

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');




$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="id11111_ab"; // Mysql username 
$password="*****"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="id11111_cd"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="ef"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select database.
$link = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $db_name);

// Retrieve data from database 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM scores ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 10";
$result = mysqli_query($link,$sql);

// Start looping rows in mysql database.
while($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
echo $rows['name'] . "|" . $rows['score'] . "|";

// close while loop 
}
?>
```

Comment: What is the value of var_dump($link)

Comment: If your query result is a boolean, then your query failed. You need to check for errors to see why

Comment: Im sorry but I have no idea. I was following a guide to make a Global HighScore setup and he used this code

Comment: Check out this Q&A to see how to set up error reporting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662488/how-to-get-mysqli-error-information-in-different-environments

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: This question is practically Stack Overflow's national anthem. I'm amazed that people can create them given how the titles have to be unique.

Comment: A lot of problems can be detected and resolved by [enabling exceptions in `mysqli`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14578243/turning-query-errors-to-exceptions-in-mysqli) so mistakes aren't easily ignored.

Comment: @tadman the line number varies ;)

Answer (score 0):

[mysqli_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) returns `false` if it fails. Subsequently, the `mysqli_fetch_array()` function is being passed this `false` boolean value, on which it can't operate. You'd be wise to check the value that `mysqli_query()` returns isn't false prior to attempting to retrieve the resource. E.g.:

```
$result = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
if (!$result) {
    die('Query failed');
}
```

Comment: Ok, i get the gist of it. how do i proceed than?

Comment: I'd suggest you check your query and database. Make sure the data is present, the field names are correct, the auth info is accurate, the connection is being established, find out why the error is occurring. Setup error reporting as mentioned in one of the comments above. Find out why the query fails and then fix it.

Comment: It responded 'Query failed'

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the mysql connection is not established properly.
Check for errors using this:

```
if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
echo mysqli_connect_error();
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is the case. If the connection failed using the procedural `mysqli_connect`, then `$link` would be `false` and they would get an error when they tried to run `mysqli_query`.

Comment: The query failed, not the connection.